# Is there any ways to save a user's speech as audio file using Speech framework in ios 10?

Tags: ios, speech-to-text

I'm using Speech framework introduced in ios 10 as speech-to-text framework in my application. I did the speech-to-text live transcribe part but I haven't found a way to save the input speech as audio files.
Can anyone explain the way to save the speech to files after finishing transcribing? Or is it just impossible to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I can run an AVAudioSession and start recording simultaneously with the recognizer.